# Set MDC properties only for rabbitmq events

Tags: spring-rabbit, mdc

I  want to apply filters to log only for  rabbit events using MDC properties.
And set trace Id  && correlation id from the event header.

I already have a RequestResponseLoggingFilter which is used for setting the tenant Id.

I am not sure how to trigger this filter only for async rabbit events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `MessageListener` or `@RabbitListener` you can add a `MessagePostProcessor` to the listener container (or listener container factory, respectively) in the `afterReceivePostProcessors` property.

The post processor(s) are called after a message is received and before the listener is called.

Comment: That's great for setting, but what about clearing? MDC.clear() afterwards is important too to prevent leaking data between requests

Comment: You can add an around advice to the container's advice chain.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell but I'm not totally clear. Where should I add it and can I add it to every listener or do I need to add an AOP annotation to every method that listens for messages?

Comment: No; it goes on the container factory - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70306081/how-to-add-an-around-advice-to-rabbitlistener/70306082#70306082