# How to Add an Around Advice to RabbitListener

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Asked and answered in reponse to [Set MDC properties only for rabbitmq events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286491/set-mdc-properties-only-for-rabbitmq-events/60286827#comment124278519_60286827)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `MethodInterceptor` bean and wire it into the container factory:

```java
@Bean
MethodInterceptor interceptor(AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory<AbstractMessageListenerContainer> factory) {
    MethodInterceptor inter = invocation -> {
        try {
            // do something before
            return invocation.proceed();
        }
        finally {
            // do something after
        }
    };
    factory.setAdviceChain(inter);
    return inter;
}
```